# What shells use readline?

Tags: shell, readline

I recently posted [a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/689394/22222) about a strange behavior I had observed in the `bash`, `fish` and `zsh` shells that was not exhibited by the `tcsh`, `csh`, `ksh`, or `dash` shells. It turns out the behavior was caused by [a change](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1954366) in the default settings of the `readline` library and I fixed it by adding `set enable-bracketed-paste Off` to my `~/.inputc`.

This got me wondering. Why did this only affect that specific subset of shells on my system? Don't all shells use `readline`? Is there some sort of general rule? Why did `bash`, `zsh` and `fish` change their behavior while the other shells did not?

Comment: See also [What popular programs use GNU Readline?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/553505/86440)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`readline` is implemented alongside `bash` by the same author and used by `bash` and among popular shells, mostly only `bash`.

The `readline` library was spawned off bash. `bash` 1.02's `ChangeLog` file has:

> ```
> Wed Jun 28 16:51:42 1989  Brian Fox  (bfox at aurel)
>
>   * New directory: LIB contains readline and history stuff,
>     and is Make-able on its own.  Also contains its own
>     ChangeLog
>
>   * history.c: removed shell dependent stuff, made into standalone
>     library.
>
> Tue Jun 27 13:05:54 1989  Brian Fox  (bfox at aurel)
>
>   * readline.c: removed shell dependent stuff.
>
>   * New file: bashline.c contains all of the shell specific
>     readline material in an attempt to begin using the
>     readline stuff as a library.
>
>
> Mon Jun 26 13:35:16 1989  Brian Fox  (bfox at aurel)
> [...]
>   * readline.c, jobs.c
>      Make commands that do not complete sucessfully restore the
>      tty state to whatever it was before the command was executed.
> ```

`zsh` used a modified version of `bash`'s readline in it first 1.0 version in 1990 as its own line editor was not ready yet, but switched to its own in 2.0 four months later in 1991. From the `README` file in 1.0:

> This is version v1.0 of zsh.  I incorporated the GNU "readline"
> editor, written by Brian Fox, into the shell, just to make my life
> temporarily easier.  I made lots of changes to it, so if there are any
> bugs in the editor, they're probably my fault.  readline will not be a
> part of the next version of zsh.

Ash-based shells typically use BSD's libedit (in the case of `dash` it's often not enabled at compile time as `dash` is only intended for running scripts, not as an interactive shell).

The clone of the Unix V10 / Plan9 `rc` shell by Byron Rakitzis gives you a choice of line editors at compile time: GNU `readline`, Simmule Turner's `editline` and Gert-Jan Vons's `vrl`. The first version only offered readline. `es` and `akanga`, based on `rc` offer a choice of `readline` vs `editline`.

busybox has its own line editor which is used by its `hush` and `ash` based shells as well as other applets such as its `bc`, `ed`, `fdisk`.

`readline` is great in that it provides a line editor that can be (and [is](/q/553505)) used in many different tools, providing consistency but, though it's probably one of the most if not the most feature-rich general purpose line editing libraries, it is relatively limited in what you can do with it. It's also licensed under the GPL, so can only be used in software licensed under the [GPL or compatible](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses).

Most shells including ksh, pdksh and derivatives, tcsh, zsh, fish or yash have their own line-editor, often more advanced. The line editors of ksh were written circa 1983 long before `bash`, and that's the interface that bash's readline mostly copied. `pdksh` and `tcsh` line editors also predate bash and readline. A `vi`-style line editor is specified by POSIX, based on ksh's. The `emacs` one is not specified by POSIX as Richard Stallman (the main author of GNU `emacs` and incidentally also came up with the "POSIX" name) objected to it¹.

Note that there are good reasons why you would want to enable the bracketed paste mode in terminal editors or line editors that support it. See: [How can I protect myself from this kind of clipboard abuse?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39118).

---

<sup>¹ See *"In early proposals, the KornShell-derived emacs mode of command line editing was included, even though the emacs editor itself was not. The community of emacs proponents was adamant that the full emacs editor not be standardized because they were concerned that an attempt to standardize this very powerful environment would encourage vendors to ship strictly conforming versions lacking the extensibility required by the community. The author of the original emacs program also expressed his desire to omit the program. Furthermore, there were a number of historical systems that did not include emacs, or included it without supporting it, but there were very few that did not include and support vi. The shell emacs command line editing mode was finally omitted because it became apparent that the KornShell version and the editor being distributed with the GNU system had diverged in some respects. The author of emacs requested that the POSIX emacs mode either be deleted or have a significant number of unspecified conditions. Although the KornShell author agreed to consider changes to bring the shell into alignment, the standard developers decided to defer specification at that time. At the time, it was assumed that convergence on an acceptable definition would occur for a subsequent draft, but that has not happened, and there appears to be no impetus to do so. In any case, implementations are free to offer additional command line editing modes based on the exact models of editors their users are most comfortable with."* in [the RATIONALE section of the POSIX `sh` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_18).</sup>

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. And I have now seen that the change in `~/.inputrc` that fixed my problem works in bash but not zsh, so presumably zsh's line editor has made the same change as readline and I would have to find the zsh equivalent fix.

Comment: @terdon, bracketed paste was enabled in zsh in 2015 in 5.1 and was made the default from the start. bash added it in 4.4 in 2016, but not enabled by default before 5.1 in late 2020.